# Poner botón para ejecutar la camera

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, kivy

Amigos tengo un código en python, resulta me ayudaron a escribirlo soy nuevo en python, y más en kivy, tengo un pequeño dilema y no sé cómo hacer tengo un código que apenas se ejecuta, se abre la cámara web pero no quiero que se ejecute apenas ejecute el codigo, lo que me sirve para entender mejor es poner un botón que cuando le dé click, si me active la cámara espero me puedan ayudar gracias amigos, este es el código que tengo:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock
import cv2

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image:
        id: img1
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.7
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.1
        Button:
           text: "Iniciar"
'''

class CvCamera(App):
    def build(self):
        self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        layout = Builder.load_string(kv)

        while not self._cap.isOpened():
            pass

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 30.0)
        return layout

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, img = self._cap.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
        texture1 = Texture.create(size=(img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture1.blit_buffer(img.tostring(), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.root.ids.img1.texture = texture1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CvCamera().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de inicializar la cámara (llamar a `cv2.cv.VideoCapture`) en build o en el inicializar, debes hacerlo en otro método y enlazarlo con el evento `on_press` del botón.

He cambiado bastante tu implementación original, pero te dejo un ejemplo reproducible que permite iniciar y detener a captura repetidas veces con el mismo botón:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock
import cv2


CAMERA_IDX = 0

kv = '''
<CameraLayout>:
    camera_display: img
    camera_button: btn
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image:
        id: img
        opacity: 1 if self.texture else 0
        size_hint: 1, 0.7

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.1
        Button:
            id: btn
            text: "Iniciar"
            on_press: root.init_camera()
'''


class CameraLayout(BoxLayout):
    camera_display = ObjectProperty()
    camera_button: ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._cap = None

    def init_camera(self): 
        self.camera_button.disabled = True
        if not self.camera_display.texture:
            self.camera_button.text = "Iniciando cámara"

            if self._cap is None:
                self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(CAMERA_IDX)

            if self._cap is None or not self._cap.isOpened():
                self.camera_button.text = "Cámara no disponible"
                Clock.schedule_once(self._btn_restart, 2)
            else:
                self.camera_button.text = "Detener"
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 30.0)
                self.camera_button.disabled = False
        else:
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
            self.camera_display.texture = None
            self._btn_restart()

    def _btn_restart(self, *args):
        self.camera_button.text = "Iniciar"
        self.camera_button.disabled = False

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, img = self._cap.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
        texture1 = Texture.create(size=(img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture1.blit_buffer(img.tostring(), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.camera_display.texture = texture1


class CvCamera(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return CameraLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CvCamera().run()
```